# How can we determine Intel Pentium page table size?

Tags: size, paging, intel, x86

Let's suppose we have a computer with Intel Pentium CPU. Its OS implements virtual memory with paging. If a process has access to 16 MBytes of memory in total, how can I calculate the minimum (best case) and the maximum (worst case) size of page tables in kBytes?

My calculations so far:
Minimum - Best case:
Size of PageTable (bytes) = Number of Entries in PageTable * Size of Entry
=> Size of PageTable (bytes) = 2^20 * 2^10 = 2^30 bytes

Maximum - Worst case:
Size of PageTable (bytes) = Number of Entries in PageTable * Size of Entry
=> Size of PageTable (bytes) = 2^20 * 2^14 = 2^34 bytes

Are those calculations correct and if yes how can I proceed to find the total size of page tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem

[Getting Intel Pentium page Table Size](http://www.rcollins.org/articles/4mpages/4MOverview.html)

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I have already read this article.